# Query SharePoint Online choice field from C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I need to return the choices in a SharePoint Online Choice field.  Note: I do not need the selected value for a given list item, I need the contents of the Choice field itself.

Here is what I'm trying. I can interrogate ff and see the CHOICES in the ff.SchemaXML but I can't see how to extract the values.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

 string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(_list);
 ClientContext ctx = GetSharePointLogin(siteUrl);
 List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My List Name");
 ctx.Load(targetList);
 ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
 FieldCollection f = targetList.Fields;
        ctx.Load(f);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
        Field ff = f.GetFieldByInternalName("Disease_x0020_Option");
        ctx.Load(ff);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figures this out by:

```
FieldChoice ff = (FieldChoice)f.GetFieldByInternalName("Disease_x0020_Option");
ctx.Load(ff);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then I could loop over ff.Choices